# Ruby On Rails: Initialize object with random GUID on ".new"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby & Rails... the goal is to create a **User** class whose primary key (*id*) is not an integer, but a GUID. I think I have the ActiveRecord end of things setup properly (not auto-generating an *id* column with type *integer*, but with column *id* of type *string* instead), and a function that can generate a GUID.

The only missing piece at this point is getting Rails to initialize a new *User* class' with an *id* using the *generate_guid* function I had wrote.

**My question**: How do I get Rails to initialize *id* with a random GUID? For example...

```
@user = User.new
@user.id
> 'AG5CE52' # <-- A randomly generated GUID...
```

It's also important to consider that if an instance of *User* is loaded from the database, it shouldn't change the *id* of the already existing user; a GUID should only be generated when I user is being created for the first time.

Here are some code samples:

**The model**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_guid  # This doesn't seem to do anything (when I call User.new)

  set_primary_key :id

  protected

  def generate_guid
    begin
      id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.where(:id => id).exists?
    self.id = id
  end
end
```

**The migration**:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users, {:id => false} do |t|
      t.string :id
      ...
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
end
```

Suggestions are appreciated!

- Dave

Comment: IMHO, Rails doesn't like when you mess with it's primary key... things start to get ugly when you add associations, etc.  You can do it, but it's not nice.  Why not add a "guid" field to Users and assign it to that, keeping the standard integer id for internal Rails use?

Comment: I understand the sentiment, but it seems silly to need two concurrent IDs that really duplicate each others purpose... inevitably, you'll only end up using the primary key ID, as that's the easiest/most useful (and I don't want to use ints for user IDs.) I 'told' Rails the GUID is my primary ID (in the model), but I'll keep this in mind if I find it still doesn't play nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `after_initialize` callback, that is called every time an object of your class is instantiated.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_initialize :generate_guid, unless: :guid
   def generate_guid
     self.guid = # your method here
   end
 end
```

you can also set this field to be a primary key in your migration:

```
create_table :users, primary_key: :guid do |t|
```

however, do you really need to create a guid every time you instantiate an object ? It seems really computationaly expensive. And as someone commented, be warned that rails sometimes behaves weirdly when you get out of common patterns and conventions...

Comment: I suppose it isn't *absolutely* necessary to call everytime I instantiate, I just don't want to be forced to manually call "generate_guid" everytime I want to create a new User.

I did a little reading, and evidently the "before_create" will invoke the "generate_guid" before it inserts a new user into my DB, which effectively addresses the performance consideration you raised, as well as satisfying my original goal.